# What's the point of appealing the 9th circuit case to the Supreme Court?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump

The 9th circuit recently ruled against the US government in relation to Trump's executive order stopping immigration from 7 countries. However this case was an appeal against a temporary restraining order from a federal court. The federal court case will now move to a full consideration.

What is the point of appealing the 9th circuit ruling to the Supreme Court when it is about such a temporary ruling of a lower federal court?  Even if the government wins it won't be relevant any more.

Comment: Probably a better fit on the law site, as this is a purely legal question.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg It is 50/50 I think. I am not sure the law sites answer "What is the point" questions.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Having said that, if you can migrate it please do. I can't delete the question any more.

Comment: I believe the Trump administration tried to have the case dropped entirely, since the two primary plaintiffs have been released and a decision will no longer affect them. The 9th Circuit disallowed this, possibly because the actual suit also included "those similarly situated", which could include tens of thousands of other people.

Answer (score 18):

Precedent.

Remember, [Roe vs Wade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roe_v._Wade) was decided almost three years after the child in question was born. It was argued that because the child had already been born, Roe would not be affected by the ruling and as such did not present a actual case or controversy. However, due to the timescales that the court works on, often years just to reach the supreme court, and then potentially years to for them to make a decision. The case fell under an established exception to the rule: one that allowed consideration of an issue that was "capable of repetition, yet evading review."

[Trump's Executive order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_Order_13769), whatever its legality, is only for a relatively brief period of 120 days. This would mean that it may be impossible to review it before it is over. This could create a situation that is "capable of repetition, yet evading review."

Comment: But the precedent would be about the TRO (temporary restraining order) and not about any ruling of constitutionality of the executive order, wouldn't it?  If they want the Supreme Court to rule on the constitutionality of the executive order it seems they have to wait for a lower federal court to rule on that first.

Comment: @felipa - yes but in the future a SC Ruling could be used in arguements against a TRO assuming the SC does not boot this one like they have some others.

Comment: @DrunkenSanta9035768 OK so potentially there are two separate Supreme Court cases. One about TROs and the other about the constitutionality of this executive order.  I wonder if the Supreme Court will regard it as a waste of their time to consider them separately.

Comment: @felipa - No they wont they typically rule on the procedural issues before the legality issues.  If there is a problem with the procedure to get there... in this case the TRO they would rule on the TRO and send it back to the court to adjudicate with the new direction from the higher court.  The same case could end up back befoer the SC for arguements about the consititutionality

Comment: While the main chunk of the order is temporary, the suspension of Syrian refugees is indefinite. That provision may still be in effect whenever the court hears the case.

Comment: @AndrewPiliser Right but the ruling that just happened by the 9th circuit only relates to the TRO not to the constitutionality of the executive order. The federal court has yet to rule on that and hence there has yet to be an appeal.

Comment: Trump's order calls for indefinite suspension of the entry of nationals "from" countries that have been found administratively not to supply "information needed for [visa] adjudications."  Also, as noted by @AndrewPiliser, it calls for an indefinite ban on refugees from Syria.  So there you have two classes of people for whom the order could be in effect indefinitely.

Comment: @felipa you are correct, but this answer says that the court case could be rendered moot because "it may be impossible to review it before it is over."  That part of this answer is incorrect, because the order does not actually expire after 120 days.

Answer (score 6):

> What is the point of appealing the 9th circuit ruling to the Supreme Court when it is about such a temporary ruling of a lower federal court? Even if the government wins it won't be relevant any more.

The Supreme Court can also offer immediate relief, just as the appeals court could.  I.e. they could remove the temporary restraining order and send the rest of the case back.

They usually don't act that quickly.  However, they could if they wanted to do so.  Note that [Bush v. Gore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_v._Gore) was decided in a couple days.  They voted on December 9th in response to an action on December 8th.

It's also possible that a particular Justice (Kennedy for the 9th) could end the temporary restraining order.

Answer (score 1):

The executive order was, I believe, a short-term (yes, a relative term) hold on pretty much all immigrants from the named countries.  A full hearing on a case can take weeks, months or even longer before a final ruling comes down.

So, if Trump issues an executive order putting a 90 day or even a 6 month hold on immigrants, a "temporary" stay for a case that takes 6 or more months to decide will render the case, itself, irrelevant, since Trump's Order would have expired, unenforced, before the case ever gets decided.

Leaving it in place essentially nullifies the Order, with the final ruling on the case only determining whether it was legal in the first place, not whether it can be carried out.

So, in a case like this, whether it is stayed or not while the case continues has a greater impact than, say, putting a hold on a law with no end-time built into it.

Comment: Trump's order does not actually expire after 90 days.  It provides for indefinite suspension of the entry of nationals "from" countries that have been found administratively not to supply "information needed for [visa] adjudications."

Comment: @phoog But were those parts of the order that are indefinite covered by the court order suspending it?

Comment: @gerrit Good point.  The section concerning "information needed for adjudications" is 3(e), which is not covered by the TRO.  (The section indefinitely suspending the entry of Syrian refugees is 5(c), which *is* covered by the TRO).